# Learning functional programming after other programming paradigms

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have taught myself C, Python, Java and a few other procedural or object oriented languages to an intermediate degree from resouces on the internet (thanks SO :D) and in books. When I tried to learn Haskell, I couldn't wrap my head around what the code actually did.

Is there a better functional language for someone coming from a background in procedural or object oriented programming to learn? Are there any resources meant for people in my situation?

Thanks!

Comment: I've voted to close this question as primarily opinion based since everyone has a language they like best, but if you want to look at functional programming in other languages then I would tell you to start with Python.  There are numerous resources out there for functional programming in Python if you google around for them.  Alternatively, look at Scala as a JVM FP language, it can seamlessly use Java libraries, and still has lots of OOP, but plenty of FP mixed in.  If .NET is more of your thing, F# is the top contender.  Like Scala it mixes OOP and FP too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably varies with people (and this question is bound to get closed over that), but the way I see it: there isn't a stair you need to step on before you can be within reach to Haskell.

So I'd say you're not driven temporarily off necessarily by the language, but by your sources of learning. For the only truly gentle introduction, I recommend [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com). It keeps things within reasonable difficulty and it has some really entertaining points every now and then.

However, if you still want to almost-soften your transition, you can check out F# which isn't a functional language but it will give you a good taste of FP, and it will be very familiar to you because you still live in an OO world.
You can also check out basically any other functional language and it will give you some of the mindset (Scala, ML, etc.).

Keep in mind that I say "almost-soften", because Haskell is very different (especially because of purity), and that gives you a very logical and mathematical mindset to things and that has been very different for me than any other language I learned. It's incredible. It was much beyond learning different syntax, it's a way to think about things and I can always find myself learning more and a truly amazing part of it is that (since it's so logical, mathematical, reasonable, etc.) the new ways of thinking I acquire with Haskell don't leave me both when I use other languages and even in my personal daily life.

That being said, the only thing truly horrible with Haskell is that it ruined me for other languages. I used to like C#... :(

Comment: By the by, in the last sentence the only thing I'm kidding about is that it's something negative. Other than that I'm serious; after learning Haskell I really don't like working in other languages so much (still do if they fit better, of course).

Comment: What does make F# not a functional language ? It has high-order function,currying, Algebric data types etc ...

Comment: @mb14 F# is considered a multi-paradigm programming language, not a FP language (see wiki). It's not to say it doesn't have FP construct (it does), it's to say that it's just different, mainly for also supporting OO and imperative programming. I'd also say it doesn't have some vital FP constructs by the way, but that's not the reason it's not a functional language. You might also want to check the very first few minutes in this [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pOl4E8x3fmw#t=25) by Eric Meijer, he refers specifically to F# on this matter; it's in an amusing tone but the point is valid.